# Does MariaDB support nested transactions?

Tags: mariadb

Does MariaDB support *nested* transactions (not savepoints)?

I want to be able to use nested transactions in stored procedures.  Currently in MySQL I am passing a parameter, "useTransaction" to each stored procedure, which controls if I start a new transaction in the body of that stored procedure.

It would more more convenient if transactions could be nested [like this](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17076_02/html/gsg_txn/C/nestedtxn.html).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Nope. But MariaDB has @@in_transaction, which tells you if a transaction is already in progress.

Answer (score 3):

No, but both MariaDB and MySQL have [chained transactions](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/start-transaction/):

```
START TRANSACTION;
[do e.g. an insert here]
COMMIT AND CHAIN;
[do e.g. another insert here]
COMMIT AND CHAIN;
[do e.g. yet another insert here]
COMMIT;
```